# Can't load image jsp

Tags: jsp

I am new to jsp and I want to add an image in an array.
The code:

```
<%
int row = 6;
int col = 5;

ArrayList<String> allImages = new ArrayList<String>();

for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
        if (i == (row - 1) && j == (col - 1))
            allImages.add("no_image");
        else
            allImages.add("WEB-INF/car" + i + j + ".jpg");
    }
}

//shuffle the list to generate random puzzle every time
Collections.shuffle(allImages);
... %>
```

Initially I think it was more photos that were inserted in an array and randomly it was chosen one. But now I want just a single photo to be inserted in the array but also it can't see the path for the photo.How can I do to resolve this?
Thank you!

Comment: Don't put your images in WEB-INF. The browser can't get them there. It is restricted.

Comment: Then where should I put it? Now I tried to put it in the folder source, but nothing..

Comment: We need more details and more code in order to help you. You can put your images anywhere a browser can access them.